# Canyouseeme.org Says I have a different ip address (PortForwarding) Motorola

Tags: ip, router, port-forwarding

I recently tried to start up a Runescape private server. However, when I go and port forward everything works out, but then if I see if it's open it's not and I have a different IP address displayed as my IP.. I don't know what the deal is I'll upload screenshots..
I'm not sure where it's getting that ip on canyouseeme.org So I don't know how to port forward that address.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's because of how networking works. Everything behind your router is going through a NAT (network address translation) which means that your whol house hold shares only one IP address when it passes through the router, but behind the router each device has a unique ip, but this is only unique behind the router. This is also the reason that port forwarding is necessary, otherwise the router would not know which computer to send the request to.

Answer (score 0):

As ohope5 says, your ISP assigns your home router a single IP address, which is shared by all of your networked devices when they connect to the internet.

You can get dynamic domain-name resolution (Dynamic DNS), so that you can connect to your game sever using a hostname (e.g http://facebook.com) instead of an ip address (e.g. `http://173.252.110.27` — which stackoverflow forbids linking to). There are many DNS providers which provide this service for *free*, or for a small charge. [Dns Dynamic](http://www.dnsdynamic.org/) is one such service, which I've never used. In fact, some routers have built-in support for a few of the most popular DDNS solutions.

[Dyndns](http://dyn.com/dns/) (my favorite) used to provide a free service, but it seems they've changed policy since last I checked.